# assignment overloading explicitly calls destructor(After execution of other binary overloaded operators)

Tags: c++, operator-overloading, destructor, dynamic-arrays

My problem is easy( double free or corruption (fasttop): ) and there is a solution for this ([here](http://www.ittc.ku.edu/~niehaus/classes/268-f08/notes/copy-assign-4.pdf)). But, I couldn't implement it. I don't know where is the problem. When I'd traced my program I saw that it happens after binary operators execution...
As an example;

`arr1 = arr2 + arr3;`

After execution this statement it calls destructor. So my destructor will call end of the scope so that it is called more than required.
My Class definition is;

```
class IntArray
{
public:
    IntArray(int size);
    //IntArray(const IntArray& ref);
    ~IntArray();
    IntArray& operator= (const IntArray&);
    const int& operator[] (int index) const;
    friend ostream& operator <<(ostream&, IntArray);
    friend istream& operator >>(istream&, IntArray);
    friend IntArray operator *(const IntArray&, const IntArray&);
    friend IntArray operator +(const IntArray&, const IntArray&);
    friend IntArray operator -(const IntArray&, const IntArray&);
    friend bool operator ==(const IntArray&, const IntArray&);
    friend bool operator <(const IntArray&, const IntArray&);
    friend bool operator >(const IntArray&, const IntArray&);
    const int& getArr(const int index) const{
        return arr[index];
    }
    void setArr(int value, int index){
        arr[index] = value;
    }
private:
    int* arr;
    int sz;
};
```

And my destructor is;

```
IntArray::~IntArray(){
    delete[] arr;
}
```

And one of my binary overloading functions;

```
 IntArray operator- (const IntArray& refOne, const IntArray& refTwo){
        IntArray newArray(refOne.sz);
        int value;
        for(int i = 0; i < refOne.sz-1; i++){
                value = refOne.getArr(i) - refTwo.getArr(i);
                newArray.setArr(value, i);
            }
        return newArray;
    }
```

Whether it needs or not, here my constructor;

```
IntArray::IntArray(int size){
    sz = size;
    arr = new int[size];
    for (int i = 0;i < size; i++)
        arr[i] = 0;
}
```

I didn't use copy constructor. Instead I used assignment operator.
And my all code is;

```
/*
 * sampleArrayImplemtation.cpp
 *
 *  Created on: Jul 31, 2012
 *      Author: musbuntu
 */

#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
using namespace std;
class IntArray
{
public:
    IntArray(int size);
    //IntArray(const IntArray& ref);
    ~IntArray();
    IntArray& operator= (const IntArray&);
    const int& operator[] (int index) const;
    friend ostream& operator <<(ostream&, IntArray);
    friend istream& operator >>(istream&, IntArray);
    friend IntArray operator *(const IntArray&, const IntArray&);
    friend IntArray operator +(const IntArray&, const IntArray&);
    friend IntArray operator -(const IntArray&, const IntArray&);
    friend bool operator ==(const IntArray&, const IntArray&);
    friend bool operator <(const IntArray&, const IntArray&);
    friend bool operator >(const IntArray&, const IntArray&);
    const int& getArr(const int index) const{
        return arr[index];
    }
    void setArr(int value, int index){
        arr[index] = value;
    }
private:
    int* arr;
    int sz;
};
IntArray& IntArray::operator= (const IntArray& ref){
    if(this!=&ref){
        delete[] arr;
        sz = ref.sz;
        arr = new int[sz];
        for (int i=0; i<sz;i++)
            arr[i] = ref.arr[i];
    }
    return *this;
}
bool operator< (const IntArray& valOne, const IntArray& valTwo){
    int flag(0);
    for(int i = 0;i<valOne.sz;i++)
    {
        if (valOne[i] < valTwo[i]){
            flag = 1;
        }
        else{
            return(0);
        }
    }
    return(flag);
}
bool operator> (const IntArray& valOne, const IntArray& valTwo){
    int flag(0);
    for(int i = 0;i<valOne.sz;i++)
    {
        if (valOne[i] > valTwo[i]){
            flag = 1;
        }
        else{
            return(0);
        }
    }
    return(flag);
}

bool operator== (const IntArray& valOne, const IntArray& valTwo){
    int flag(0);
    for(int i = 0;i<valOne.sz;i++)
    {
        if (valOne[i] == valTwo[i]){
            flag = 1;
        }
        else{
            return(0);
        }
    }
    return(flag);
}
IntArray operator- (const IntArray& refOne, const IntArray& refTwo){
    IntArray newArray(refOne.sz);
    int value;
    for(int i = 0; i < refOne.sz-1; i++){
            value = refOne.getArr(i) - refTwo.getArr(i);
            newArray.setArr(value, i);
        }
    return newArray;
}
IntArray operator+ (const IntArray& refOne, const IntArray& refTwo){
    IntArray newArray(refOne.sz);
    int value;
        for(int i = 0; i < refOne.sz-1; i++){
            value = refOne.getArr(i) + refTwo.getArr(i);
                newArray.setArr(value, i);
            }
    return newArray;
}
IntArray operator* (const IntArray& refOne, const IntArray& refTwo){
    IntArray newArray(refTwo.sz);
    int value;
        for(int i = 0; i < refOne.sz-1; i++){
                value = refOne.getArr(i) * refTwo.getArr(i);
                newArray.setArr(value, i);
            }
    return newArray;
}
istream& operator>> (istream& inputStream, IntArray ref){
    cout << "Enter one by one with respect to a comma> ";
    for(int i = 0; i < ref.sz; i++){
        inputStream >> ref.arr[i];
    }
    return inputStream;
}
ostream& operator<< (ostream& outStream, IntArray ref){
    outStream << "\nYour array has size = " << ref.sz << " and all members are:" << endl;
    for (int i = 0; i < ref.sz; i++){
        outStream << ref[i] << "\t";
    }
    return outStream;
}
const int& IntArray::operator[] (int index) const{
    if (index >= 0 && index < sz){
        return(arr[index]);
    }
    else{
        cerr << "Index out of range, therefore use vectors instead." << endl;
    }
//  return(arr[1]);
}
IntArray::IntArray(int size){
    sz = size;
    arr = new int[size];
    for (int i = 0;i < size; i++)
        arr[i] = 0;
}
//IntArray::IntArray(const IntArray& ref){
//  arr = new int[ref.sz];
//  for(int i=0;i<ref.sz;i++)
//      arr[i] = ref.arr[i];
//}
IntArray::~IntArray(){
    delete[] arr;
}

int main(){
    int sz;
    cout << "Enter size of array> ";
    cin >> sz;
    IntArray arr1(sz);
    arr1.setArr(5, 3);
    IntArray arr2(sz);
    //arr2 = arr1;
    IntArray arr3(sz), arr4(sz), arr5(sz), arr6(sz);
    arr2.setArr(2, 1);
    arr6 = arr1;
    cout << arr6;
    arr3 = arr2 - arr1;
    arr4 = arr1 * arr2;
    arr5 = arr2 + arr1;
    if (arr6 == arr5)
        cout << "It's working.";
    if (arr2 < arr5)
        cout << "It's working, too";
    if (arr4 > arr2)
        cout << "It is also working.";
    cout << arr1 << arr2 << arr3 << arr4 << arr5 << arr6;
    return 0;
}
```

In order to cope with this problem I had to use deep copy;
And to do this; ( According to wikipedia [article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Copy_constructor#User-defined_copy_constructor): )
First add this library/header:

```
#include <algorithm>
```

And a deep copy constructor:

```
IntArray(const IntArray& ref):sz(ref.sz), arr(new int[ref.sz]){
    copy(ref.arr, ref.arr + ref.sz, arr);
}
```

Thanks for your patience and advices...

Comment: 1. What's the problem? 2. Implement a copy constructor.

Comment: Hi @LuchianGrigore,
I want to implement assignment overloading. So I don't need to use a copy constructor

Comment: Your "destructor" doesn't look like a destructor.

Comment: @mustaa: Copy construction happens often. Very often. So often, that you wouldn't believe how often it happens.

Comment: I'm sorry for sending incomplete question but somehow I forgot to send some information about my question. @Zeta my instructor's solved a question as this in class. So I thought I should use assignment operator overloading instead using a copy constructor.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Respect the [rule of three](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rule_of_three_%28C%2B%2B_programming%29)**. All your binary operations are wrong otherwise:

```
IntArray operator- (const IntArray& refOne, const IntArray& refTwo){
    IntArray newArray(refOne.sz);
    int value;
    for(int i = 0; i < refOne.sz-1; i++){
            value = refOne.getArr(i) - refTwo.getArr(i);
            newArray.setArr(value, i);
        }
    return newArray;
}
```

You return a `IntArray` by value, a copy is created, and the compiler-generated copy constructor is used. If you want this to behave correctly, you have to implement a copy constructor.

If instead of commenting it out:

```
public:
   IntArray(int size);
   //IntArray(const IntArray& ref);
```

you could have define it private:

```
public:
   IntArray(int size);
private:
   //IntArray(const IntArray& ref);
```

and the problem would have been clear from compilation time.

Comment: That means I should return a reference instead of a value?

Comment: @mustaa no, it means you should implement the copy constructor!

Comment: @mustaa Nooo! It wouldn't make sense to return a value from `operator+` (but it does make sense for `operator+=`. Implement the copy constructor to make a deep copy of the underlying dynamically allocated data.

Comment: @mustaa returning a reference to a local variable is undefined behavior.